# Create New Dynamic disk in Windows 8 for Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, partitioning, windows-8

I'm trying to dual boot with ubuntu. So, create a new partition/ree unallocated space in Windows 8 for ubuntu. But then since its a dynamic disk, ubuntu doesn't detect free unallocated space.

When I list the drives in DISKPART, it list all my 3 current partitions into 1 major DISK0. There are no other disks.

[image]

I was thinking if I could create one extra disk and convert it to basic volume and use this for ubuntu.

I don't want to lose my Windows 8 installation, C drive softwares, D drive data.

How should  do it?

Comment: You can not install Ubuntu on a Dynamic Disk. You need to convert it to a Basic Disk first.